Ubuntu 22.04 home directory encryption on a shared computer
First time poster, hi!
I'm an IT support person and I have a need to explore what encrypting home directories on a shared machine running Ubuntu 22.04 would look like. I have read this article that seems to have some good instructions, but it doesn't cover specifically shared machines with multiple accounts needing to log into it (and of course multiple home directories). We are trying to avoid the scenario of full disk encryption so that if the machine gets rebooted from, say, a power outage that a person doesn't have to physically go to the machine to input the disk encryption password before remote users can log into it again. So, we're thinking just encrypting the home directories might be the better way to go. Let's say there will be roughly 6 accounts that log into the shared machine.
Would I need to create a separate partition for every user account that needs to log in, in order to be able to encrypt their individual home directory?
Are there cons to following the method outlined in the popular answer in this article for a shared machine?
Are there any common/reliable utilities or apps that could be used to secure the home directories instead of using this method?
-Thank you kindly
